# Button click in Caliburn.Micro adds items to ComboBox

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro

I just started coding my simple app in C# with MahApps.Metro and Caliburn.Micro and I experienced a problem. I am not very familiar with MVVM model, so I'm trying to understand it. What I am trying to do is to fill ComboBox with items after clicking a button (button click searches for COM ports and adds COMs to combobox). Can you please tell me how to do this? This is part of my MainView.xaml:

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label Name="SelectCOM" Content="{x:Static r:Translations.SelectCOM}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" />
                        <ComboBox Width="235" 
                                  x:Name="COMPorts" 
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPort}" />
                    </WrapPanel>
                    <Button Margin="10,0,0,0" 
                            Width="70" 
                            Content="{x:Static r:Translations.Refresh}" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                            cal:Message.Attach="RefreshCOM" />
                </WrapPanel>
```

And this is my MainViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
    {
        IDevice Device = null;
        private string selectedPort;

        public void RefreshCOM()
        {
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();


        }

        public string SelectedPort
        {
            get
            {
                return this.selectedPort;
            }

            set
            {
                this.selectedPort = value;
                this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.SelectedPort);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ["bind"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2012/10/12/xaml-binding-basics-101.aspx) the list of COM ports to the control's [ItemsSource](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFItemsSource.aspx).

```
<ComboBox Width="235" 
          x:Name="COMPorts" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPort}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ComPorts}" />
```

and don't forget to update your view model (add an [observable collection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42536/List-vs-ObservableCollection-vs-INotifyPropertyCha) of com port names)

```
public class MainViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    // ...
    public MainViewModel() 
    {
      ComPorts = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }
    public void RefreshCOM()
    {
        string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        foreach(var port in ports)
        {
           ComPorts.Add(port);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> ComPorts {get; private set;}
    // ...
}
```